# Laravel eloquent model relationship don't work on blade template

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables:

```
Persons
id, name, foto_id
```

and

```
Fotos
id, url
```

On `Person` model, I added:

```
public function foto() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\\Foto","id","foto_id");
}
```

> Note that I needed to escape the `\F`...

When i try to `{{ $person->foto->url }}`, I get the **"trying to access property of non-object" error**. If I `{{ print_r($person->foto()) }}` I get just `1`...

I followed the laravel docs, and this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel)

This is a project I'm creating to learn Laravel, so any helpful advice is appreciated!

**Edit:**
In `artisan tinker`, `$person->foto->url` work as intended, returns the `Foto` object just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `belongsTo` function instead of the `hasOne`.
If you create a `Foto` model, there you'll need a `hasMany` function.

I refer to the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) for more information about this.

Comment: So i have to link the relationship on both ends (Person `hasOne` Foto, and Foto `belongsTo` Person)?

Comment: The other way around: the model representing the table that holds of the FK, uses the `belongsTo` function. The model representing the table that holds of the PK, used the `hasOne` or `hasMany` function.

Comment: This seems to be my misunderstanding! `Person` has `Foto`, so I put the FK(?) foto_id on `Persons` table, and the `Fotos` table has only `id` and `url` fields. So, only the Person should know what are it`s Fotos, and no Foto should know about to whom they belong.

Comment: That's correct, but that's only database. In laravel terms this is the `belongsTo` relation. FK = Foreign Key btw, that's the key (1 column in this case) that holds the value of the relation to another table.

Comment: Ok, i understood. What I find odd, is that if i try it in `artisan tinker`, everything works fine... I tried `$person->foto->url` and it worked as intended, with no alterations... If i add the `belongsTo` on `Foto`, it still works on thinker, and don't on blade template...